# Symfony 3 Problems FosUserBundle in resetting request

Tags: php, email, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, symfony

I had this message error 4 hours ago and I tried to resolve it but I didn't know where is the problem. Maybe all files are wrong configured? Login is OK.

**security.yml**

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            default_target_path: /
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            remember_me: true   
        remember_me:
            secret:         %secret%
            #lifetime: 30000000
        logout:  true
        anonymous:    true
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /login



access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
   # - { path: ^/listeUsers, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
   # - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
   # - { path: ^/ajouter, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/index, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
```

**config.yml**

```
 imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
#http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    translator: ~

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: gmail
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  'digita****@gmail.com'
    password:  '*******'
    spool:     { type: memory }


#FOS USERBundle
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address:        digita***.code@gmail.com
        sender_name:    DigitalCode - Sestem | Resetting Password
```

But resetting/request doesn't work. It stayed on the login interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Thunks Brother ,

u are right i make a mistake in the access_control , now it's working but with those configurations without ReGex :

```
    access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
```

Problem Solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misconfiguration in *access_control*:

see this

```
- { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

and compare it with this

```
- { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

---

I think this should work:

```
- { path: ^/resetting$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Now it should be working. I can't explain it completely but for me since the regex delimiter is missing it seems to be like its used as given not as regex as you wanted to.

Comment: What does the $ do at the of the URL?